# Is there a way to print it out where the text cursor is located instead of cmd?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, printing, text-cursor

I am creating a program using tkinter that words are stored in a button and the words are printed when the button is pressed.

I want the word to be printed where the text cursor is located(outside the program like a virtual keyboard), but when I made an exe file with pyinstaller, it was printed only in the cmd window.

I don't know if there's a way to use the print function to print it out where the text cursor is located instead of cmd, or if I should try a different approach, such as a module.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("240x240")
root.resizable(False, False)

def test():
    print("test")

basic_test = Button(root, text="test", command=test)
basic_test.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add arguments to the function to print the desired text.

To do this use a lambda. It will look like this:

```
button = Button(root, text='test', command= lambda: test('test'))
```

Comment: Did you add the parameter to the function?
`def test(text: str):
    print(text)`